# How to fill a new row in oracle with previous row values

Tags: sql, oracle, business-logic

I have a table A with below values

```
year  quarter price source
2017   1       10    s
2017   3       12    t
2018   1       10    m
2018   2       15    r
```

I would like to see the table as below. Yes, I would like to fill the non specified quarters with previous quarter values.

I thought of creating a temp table B with all quarters and do a join with this table A but how can I fill the price and source fields from previous quarter.

```
year  quarter price  source
2017   1       10      s
2017   2       10      s
2017   3       12      t
2017   4       12      t
2018   1       10      m
2018   2       15      r
```

Comment: You don't need temp tables, create missing rows using simple hierarchical generator, left join your table and finally use `lag... ignore nulls` combined with `coalesce` or `nvl`, like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38e61d/1).

Comment: I am running against  100k records and the connect runs for ever...

Answer (score 0):

For this, oracle has the LAG window function, which allows you to access previous rows. I think, it is anyways not required to fill the data to the next row as you can easily gather it when you select it.

E.g.

```
SELECT year,
   quarter,
   price,
   source,
   price,
   LAG(price, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY year, quarter) AS price_previous FROM   A;
```